bazel test execution errors on ubuntu linux `libfdb_c.so: cannot open shared object file` foundationdb file
Team, Building my first app with Bazel and getting this error. any hint?
is it missing file path or library path? if yes how do I set it as per my system?
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/src/pipelines/debugging/temporal/lib/debug_activities/mocks/mocks_mock_gomock_prog_bin_/mocks_mock_gomock_prog_bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfdb_c.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2024/05/09 23:22:44 Loading input failed: exit status 127

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/local/samu/lib:/usr/local/samu/lib64
